# SWT Program.launch mail client

Tags: java, eclipse, email, swt, mailto

I'm trying to create an email in the default email client of a linux mint machine and I have a problem that I can't understand.
I'm using **org.eclipse.swt.program.Program** to launch "mailto:email@domain.com" and it partially works. It opens Thunderbird (the default email client) and it puts the mail address to "To" field but at the begining it also adds 3 slashes, and it looks like this: "///email@domain.com" which is not correct.

The code is as simple as this:

```
String mailTo = "mailto:" + email;
Program.launch( mailTo );
```

Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can confirm this on Linux Mint with both Thunderbird and Geary. So it has to be an SWT bug. Please [post a bug report](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/bugs.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug and should be posted as such.

However, there is a workaround/alternative:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xdg-open mailto:test@test.com");
```

`xdg-open` is available on *most* (unfortunately not all) main linux distributions and will open the default application for the given parameter.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Do you know how can i use this on windows also? Is it like this: "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mailto:test@test.com");" ?

Comment: @Gheo Use `Program.launch()` on windows. It's what you usually should use.